# Unable to type Cyrillic characters in the Virtual Terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard

Even though

```
$ localectl
System Locale: LANG=en_US.utf8
VC Kemap: bg_pho-utf8
X11 Layout: bg,us
X11 Model: pc105
X11 Variant: ,phonetic
X11 Options: terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp:shifts_toggle,grp_led:scroll
```

and graphical applications correctly shift between the two layouts, I can't seem to apply the keyboard remapping in the Virtual Terminals. `showconsolefont` confirms the characters are there and `cat`ing works. It's just that I can't type Cyrillic characters. I was able to `localectl set-keymap de-latin1` and type umlauts... but I don't need umlauts.

```
Linux msi 5.10.15-arch1-1
```

Comment: What is your distro and version?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env false


# Enable reading and typing in Bulgarian in VTs.
# Source this file in your '~/.profile'.



# After executing this, hold down 'AltGr' (right Alt) while typing.
# For alternative layouts, look at the bottom of the man pages.
setfont Cyr_a8x14
sudo loadkeys bg_pho-utf8


# This is permanent until reboot and works for de-latin-1 but not for BG.
# localectl set-keymap bg_pho-utf8
```